# Center padded divs

Tags: html

I'm new to divs so please excuse my crudeness.

I would like the two divs to be centered, with space between them so they are not touching.

The CSS -

```
#div1 {
margin: 0px auto 0px;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width: 339px;
}
#div2 {
margin: 0px auto 0px;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width: 400px;
}
```

The HTML -

```
<div id="div1">
<p>Image 339 x 500 to go here</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
10-17-20 - Toronto, Ontario - Massey Hall<br />
11-21 Birmingham, England - National Indoor Arena<br />
11-22 Manchester, England - 02 Apollo Manchester<br />
11-24 Manchester, England - 02 Apollo Manchester<br />
11-25 London, England - The 02 Arena</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want them side by side or in two different 'rows' but centered across the page?

Comment: Side by side, centered

Comment: Put your "two div" in the global div with the width and margin: auto [My Codepen](http://codepen.io/ColoO/pen/IJyFg)

Comment: Tip: If you don't have a very specific reason for setting height, don't. Same goes for dimensions using pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>

#wrapper {width:90%;margin:0 auto;}
#left {float:left;width:48%;margin-right:1%;}
#right {float:right;width:48%;margin-left:1%;}
```